# Что посоветуете новичку для того чтобы разобраться, а позже может и углубиться в такие сферы как: ии, машинное обучение, нейронные сети...?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Мне посоветовали изучить:
• основы языка Python
• линейную алгебру
• теорию вероятностей
• математический анализ

Comment: Начните искать и смотреть по этим темам видео на Youtube. По ходу дела будут обнаруживаться очередные темы, которые вы не понимаете - ищите и смотрите видео по ним. И так пока всё не изучите. На Youtube есть всё, что нужно. Только найти достаточно времени на это всё.

Comment: Привет. Задавался недавно тем же вопросом, начал с прохождения курсов на Степике, они бесплатные, я записался на курс нейронных сетей, но там перед началом посоветовали пройти курс основ Python, сейчас прохожу этот курс.
Похоже на рекламу, но нет, я не пиарщик Степика)